# iptables masquerading rules for established session

Tags: firewall, iptables, port-forwarding, session

I have the following setup:

Box1 [server]:
eth0 with ip `192.168.2.18` is in the internal network with webserver running on port 80.

Box2 [gateway]: 
eth0 with ip `gw.gw.gw.gw` with some port exposed to internet e.g. port number 3000.
 
eth1 with ip `192.168.2.3` is for the internal network

Box3 [client]:
eth0 with ip `cl.cl.cl.cl`

Goal is to redirect the traffic from `gw.gw.gw.gw:3000` to `192.168.2.18:80`. It looks like simple DNAT rule would work but the problem is that gateway `gw.gw.gw.gw` is filtered by some other firewall(black-box) so that only established sessions are accepted in the output chain of the black-box. In other words, if I am listening to port 4000 at `cl.cl.cl.cl`, I won't be able to connect to `cl.cl.cl.cl:4000` from `gw.gw.gw.gw` but the other way is possible i.e. I can connect from `cl.cl.cl.cl` to `gw.gw.gw.gw:3000`. Currently, I have following rules in the gateway:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3000 -j DNAT --to 192.168.2.18:80
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE -o eth0
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -i eth0 -o eth1 -d 192.168.2.18 --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT

sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.forwarding=1    #to enable forwarding by kernel.
```

`tcpdump` show that gateway is sending response packets to the client but the client is not able to receive any. My best guess is that this is somehow related to session being lost at the iptables but I not a pro in iptables rules. Any clue as to what I could be missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the following lines should do the trick:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.18:80
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -i eth0 -o eth1 -d 192.168.2.18 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```